# How to resolve RSelenium error message "Failed to connect to localhost port 4444: Connection refused"?

Tags: r, selenium, docker

I am trying to use `RSelenium` with `Docker`to crawl a website. However, I have some issues trying to get `RSelenium`/`Docker` to work.

Specifically, I installed `Docker` on my computer, which appears to be running fine (I see the image of the whale below when I open it).

[image: Docker screenshot]

In R, I then run the following code with no problems and see the expected output.

```
shell('docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-chrome')
shell('docker ps')
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
d7de815ce644        selenium/standalone-chrome   "/opt/bin/entry_poinâ€¦"   13 minutes ago      Up 13 minutes       0.0.0.0:4445->4444/tcp   zen_mclean
```

But when I then run the following code, I always receive the following error message:

```
remDr <- RSelenium::remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost",
                             port = 4444,
                             browserName = "chrome")
remDr$open()
[1] "Connecting to remote server"
Error in checkError(res) : 
  Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Failed to connect to localhost port 4444: Connection refused
```

I am not sure what is going on here (I'm new to scraping). Can anybody help me figure out what to do here?

If it helps, I am running Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by uninstalling Docker Toolbox and VMBox, which I was using, and installing the latest version of Docker from their website instead.

Answer (score 0):

In docker, you've binded your **hosts** port 4445 to the selenium-driver port 4444.

Which means if you run R in your host, you need to specify port = 4445

Does that solve it?